# Deep linking chrome though Safari

Tags: safari, google-chrome, web-browser

I am new to this so this maybe a trivial question but I have a private web app that would like to deep link the chrome into it so when users visit it on safari I could give them the option to open chrome through the web app or when they are on chrome to be able to open Safari. However I wasn't able to do that using the URI scheme whereas I was able to do the same thing with other applications other than Safari and chrome (like open Microsoft word) I was wondering if such a deep linking possible and how and if not why?

Comment: So you basically want to add a link onto your web page which says "Reload page in Chrome" and, after the user does just that, starts Chrome on the computer of the user with your page open?

Comment: Something in that sense yes and if I can't do that then maybe just open the chrome app via an actionable button.

Comment: Deep linkin' is something different! **No deep link**: [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). **Deep link**: [Ask Different GotitJS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/249984/gotitjs) ...both linked from another site.

Comment: @klanomath My initial intent to do what patrix mentioned but I wasn't able to do that and so I wondered if I could deep link chrome app into the web app.

Comment: What if the user does not have Chrome installed on their device?

Comment: I am not worried about those corner cases. This is purely towards certain users.